# how to align javascript's equals sign in webstorm

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, webstorm

all

when i config my Webstorm9 settings like this ,it turns out that the sample code in the right aligns the equals sign properly

[image: settings]

but when i formatting my javascript code in the editor it doesn't work,it still shows

[image: results]

and what i want is align the equals sign

[image]

anyone who can take a look?

**-------EDIT------**

maybe i misunderstand the checked option,but i copy the sample code to my editor then reformat it, oh,bad result..

[image: sample code]

Answer (score 12):

In Webstorm 10,

1. Go to Settings> Editor> Code Style > JavaScript
2. Go to the "Other" tab and check "Align multiple 'var' statements and assignment" and click Ok.
3. Go to Code > Reformat code (`Ctrl + Alt + L`)

Voila!

Answer (score 12):

In **PHPStorm 2017** (and, I assume, by extension WebStorm) that behavior can be achieved by:

1. going to **Settings > Editor > Code Style > JavaScript**
2. **Wrapping and Braces** tab
3. scroll down to **Variable declarations** and set **Align** to **When Grouped**

Additionally, setting Variable declarations to **Wrap always** will result in this when reformatting:

[image]

**Update:** unchanged in **version 2018** and in WebStorm/PHPStorm **version 2019**, the steps I described above still work the same.

Answer (score 3):

**Update for WebStorm 2017.3**

Apparently, since version 2017.3, the **Other** tab has been removed from **Code Style > JavaScript**.

Now you have a couple of alignment options under the **Wrapping and Braces** tab (scroll down to the bottom):

[image]

It took me a while to figure this out, hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

**Update for Webstorm 2016.1**

[image: The Preferences Menu]

@Hudvoy still has the right answer for this. I've updated with a visual of where you need to look in Webstorm 2016.1

Comment: where's the option in Webstorm 2017.x?

Answer (score 0):

Take note that the exact phrasing of the option is

> Align **multiline** variable declaration

(emphasis mine) and that the example code shows:

```
var myLink  = {
        ....
    },
    local   = true,
    initial = -1;
```

This option only aligns the equal signs of multiline variable declarations, not a bunch of single line variable declarations in a row like in your code.

To have it automatically align them you would need to change your code to

```
a       = 1,
bbbbb   = 2,
thisisc = 3;
```

Note that you also have to add a `var` before it all, as WebStorm will assume `a=1` to be a reference to a global variable, not a variable definition.

Also note that code formatting is not automatic. You have to select `Code->Reformat Code...` from the menu, or hit `Ctrl + Alt + L` to reformat your code.

I also found that Webstorm could perform code formatting on the Javascript within either a .html or .js file, but would not work within a .php file - in PHP files it only performs syntax highlighting.

Comment: thx for your reply,and i copy the sample to my js file ,it still not working

Comment: I have installed Webstorm and tested this, see my updated answer for more details, beyond that I have no idea why it wouldn't work.

Comment: i follow the same steps like your mentioned above,still not working,i think it maybe a bug in webstorm,thank you all the same!

Comment: what is your WebStorm version? Please see [WEB-13786](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-13786) - does it look similar?